# How can i deploy my react app on any hosting like vercel / render

Tags: vercel

How can i deploy my react app on any hosting like vercel / render. I m trying both but always got the error. This is my repo on git : https://github.com/rohitdr/project.git

How can i deploy my react app on any hosting like vercel / render. I m trying both but always got the error.

Answer (score 0):

You can do one thing is move out all files and folder from backend folder to main branch directly, and delete the empty backend folder, and then you can try, this may work.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).